# Geopandas polygons which share edges with a linestring

Tags: geopandas, spatial-query

I have a MultiLineString `lines` which runs along the edges of several polygons 'poly`. All are GeoPandas GeoDataFrames.

The polygons are triangles formed through `scipy.spatial.delaunay`

I'm trying to get 3 separate bool masks to identify those polygons which share 1, 2, or 3 edges with the MultiLineString.

I've been trying every combination of:

contains/crosses/intersects/overlaps/touches/within/covers/

```
mask = poly.<method>(lines)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give the [geopandas docs on merging data](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mergingdata.html) a close read. All of those methods are binary predicates which merge the dataframes on their indexes. So unless the dataframes are already aligned, you’ll get incorrect results or nans.

You want a spatial join using [`GeoDataFrame.sjoin`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.sjoin):

```py
poly.sjoin(lines, how="left")
```

This will give you any lines which intersect the polygons.